# confused with python dictionary methods.values() .keys()

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

why this code isn't working?  trying to get returns on items which value==key

```
L=[0,2,2,1,5,5,6,10]
x=dict(enumerate(L))
y=(filter(x.keys()==x.values(), x.items()))
print(list(y))
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`keys()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys) method returns a view of all of the keys.

The [`values()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) method returns a view of all of the values.

So, `x.keys()==x.values()` is asking whether all of the keys equal all of the values, which is of course not true.

Also, `filter` wants a function. But you're not passing it a function, you're just passing it the result of `x.keys()==x.values()`, or `False`. To turn that into a function, you'd need to use `def` or `lambda` to create a new function.

---

The function you want to create is a function that takes an item, and returns true if the key equals the value. Since an item is just a 2-element tuple with the key and value for that item, the function to check that is:

```
y = filter((lambda item: item[0] == item[1]), x.items())
```

Or, if that's a bit too confusing, don't try to write it inline; just `def` it separately:

```
def key_equals_value(item):
    key, value = item
    return key == value

y = filter(key_equals_value, x.items())
```

---

However, this is pretty clumsy; it's much easier to write it as a comprehension than a `filter` call:

```
y = ((key, value) for (key, value) in x.items() if key == value)
```

As a general rule, whenever you don't already have a function to pass to `filter` or `map`, and would have to create one with `def` or `lambda`, a comprehension will usually be more readable, because you can just write the expression directly.

---

And, if you want a list rather than a generator, you can do that with a comprehension just by changing the parens to square brackets:

```
y = [(key, value) for (key, value) in x.items() if key == value]
```

---

And, if you want just the values, not the key-value pairs:

```
y = [value for (key, value) in x.items() if key == value]
```

---

If you find yourself confused by comprehensions, they can always be converted into nested statements, with an `append` at the bottom. So, that last one is equivalent to:

```
y = []
for key, value in x.items():
    if key == value:
        y.append(value)
```

---

Also, you don't really need a dict here in the first place; you just want to iterate over the index, value pairs. So:

```
y = [value for (index, value) in enumerate(L) if index == value]
```